# Hide email js script doesn't seem to work on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This is the script that I found on the net. It works fine with Firefox and Explorer, but not with Chrome. When I click on the email link the expected dialog window doesn't show up. Any solution? Thanks.

```js
/* JS */ 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".email");
  [].forEach.call(a, function(elem) {
    var href = "mailto:"+ elem.dataset.first +"."+ elem.dataset.last +"@"+ elem.dataset.domain;
    elem.setAttribute("href", href);
  })
}, false);
```

```css
/* CSS */ 

.email::before {
  content: attr(data-first) "." attr(data-last) "@" attr(data-domain);
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML CODE --> 

<a class="email" href="#" data-first="firstname" data-last="lastname" data-domain="domain.com"></a>
```

Comment: Have tried this in FF and Chrome and works for me as expected. What is the expected dialog? An email client?

Comment: Yes, you know, the typical "mailto" behavior. So does it work for you? What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be that you have older chrome version... Works fine on my chrome as well. Try this: [Example for single email](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/w76mat1p/1/), [Example for multiple emails](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/w76mat1p/2/). This jquery code should work in every browser. I accidentally used capital letters for the names, which reminded me that it would be more bulletproof if you use `.toLowerCase()`. [For example like this](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/w76mat1p/3/)

Comment: Not that it matters. Most people just like their email addresses lowercase.

Comment: No luck. I'll try on different computers and let you know.

Comment: Ok, uninstalling and reinstalling chrome fixed the problem. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help.